# How do I re-pass multiple method arguments in Ruby 1.8.5?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I'm using ruby 1.8.5 and I'd like to use a helper method to help filter a user's preferences like this:

```
def send_email(user, notification_method_name, *args)
  # determine if the user wants this email
  return if !user.send("wants_#{notification_method_name}?")

  # different email methods have different argument lengths
  Notification.send("deliver_#{notification_method_name}", user, *args)
end
```

This works in ruby 1.8.6, however when I try to do this in 1.8.5 and try to send more than one arg I get an error along the lines of:

> wrong number of arguments (2 for X)

where X is the number of arguments that particular method requires.  I'd rather not rewrite all my Notification methods - can Ruby 1.8.5 handle this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why *not* use Ruby 1.8.6?

Comment: Why not 1.8.7 which is current for Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Is there a tag for legacy versions of ruby?

Comment: it would be great to upgrade.  Unfortunately that doesn't fit in the scope of my current project.  Or answer my question regarding how to do this in 1.8.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is to switch to named-arguments using hashes:

```
def  send_email(args)
  user = args[:user]
  notification_method_name = args[:notify_name]

  # determine if the user wants this email
  return if !user.send("wants_#{notification_method_name}?")

  # different email methods have different argument lengths
  Notification.send("deliver_#{notification_method_name}", args)
end

send_email(
  :user        => 'da user',
  :notify_name => 'some_notification_method',
  :another_arg => 'foo'
)
```